# Access ext4 from Windows 10 to undo changes in 2 config files

Tags: nvidia, windows, 20.04, auto-login

When I boot up Ubuntu I get the login screen, after logging in nothing happens and the mouse freezes but the keyboard still works. This is caused by two edits in separate config files, which is why I want to access these files from Windows 10.

I recently upgraded to 20.04, however the autologin stopped working. In an attempt to fix it i edited `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` . At default there is a line "# WaylandEnable=false" I uncommented it (removed the #) and did nothing else. Second, I have a secondary screen that is rotated by 90 degrees which also did not work anymore after upgrading. Changing this in the default screen device options had no effect. However, changing it in Nvidia X server settings did have effect. These changes however, are reverted after rebooting (or relogin). There is a button to save the settings as a config file and I was curious if that config file would be loaded after reboot. So I saved the settings in the default folder (`/etc/X11` if I remember correctly) with the default file-name (which i do not remember) and then I rebooted at which the problem stated above occurred.

I tried the following:

1. I am NOT able to boot into safe mode by holding shift during boot
2. I am also NOT able to enter the GRUB menu by repeatedly hitting 'esc' during boot.
3. When the login screen appears I am not able to enter into a terminal when pressing ctrl+alt+F1 or ctrl+alt+F3. When pressing ctrl+alt+F3, the mouse stops working, but when pressing ctrl+alt+F1 it keeps working. In all cases the keyboard keeps working since I am able to reboot when pressing ctrl+alt+del.
4. I have a dual boot install, namely Ubuntu and Windows 10. I unsuccessfully tried accessing the Linux files from windows 10 with several programs. First off, this is necessary because Windows 10 is not able to read ext4, if I am able to access the ext4 partition then I can manually revert the two changes I made. The first program was diskinternals, but this program is only able to read files. The second program is ext2read which mounts the Linux partition but when accessing it, Windows 10 says it is only accessible after reformatting, so this is of no use either.
5. I do not have a USB at hand to create a live USB.
6. I suspect that installing openbox, creating a vm of a linux installation and trying to mount the partition from there also is of no use, since I suspect that Windows will need to be able to read that partition too.

So my question is, how am I able to edit the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file and the one in `/etc/X11` from Windows 10? Or how am I able to open up a terminal during/after booting Ubuntu (in case the hotkeys changed or something)?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows itself cannot recognize ext4 partitions.The fastest way is to try something like disk partition software.Almost all of them can recognize ext4.

Comment: Could you provide the name(s) of one or several programs? As stated in the question, I tried two programs but both did not work and I cannot find a program that can.

Comment: you just need to google "windows partition manager ext4" ,there are many available free software there.the folder may not appear like it was in Ubuntu,so you may need to search for the directory.

Comment: Googled it, the programs 'AOMEI Partition Assistant', 'diskgenius', 'partition guru', 'gparted', 'MiniTool Partition Wizard' and 'paragon partition manager' popped up. I looked into these but they only do what you would expect, namely managing partition. None of them provide the functionality of actually accessing/modifying files on an existing partition. Note that converting the ext4 to NTFS to access these files is not possible since the disk gets formatted.

Comment: I am really sorry but recommending software here seems to be not allowed.I can say that you'd better search ”How to read & write Linux ext4/3/2 partition on Windows?" and the top blog should be useful. https://www.eassos.com/blog/how-to-read-write-linux-ext4-ext3-ext2-partition-on-windows/                                    also,you should notice that Ubuntu usually use UTF-8 encoding,which is not by default in Windows.So you'll need a powerful text editor,by the way.

Comment: if my answer worked,please click"accept"(on the left).Thanks! :)

Comment: The blog uses partition guru, which has been bought by some Chinese company and it seemed fishy. In the end, I solved it by buying a USB and creating a live USB, from there I edited the files.